# Resources for IBM WebSphere MQ and .NET implementation

Tags: c#, sql, ibm-mq

I need help with implementing IBM WebSphere MQ for a system where the queue is supposed to send the XML messages to a SQL database. May please help me with resources and video tutorials for the matter in hand. The system will be in C#

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you wanting to access MQ?  Are you using JMS or MQI?

There are a couple different ways to access MQ from .NET.  The first way is through the native MQ interface known as MQI.  The second way is through a JMS implementation created by IBM called XMS.

The queue is not going to write anything into a database for you.  You are are going to need to create a listener application that does that.

EDIT:

If you want to use JMS then you should take a look at the doc link that Shashi posted below.  [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)

You will want to look at the docs under "Message Service Client .NET, Version 2.0.0"  --> "Developing XMS Applications" --> "Writing XMS .NET applications"

Also take a look at the sample applications that are packaged with the client.

Essentially what you are going to end up doing is creating a connection to the queue manager (either remote or local depending on your use case), creating a destination object that will represent the queue you are trying to work with on the queue manager, and then creating a listener to receive messages from the queue (either sync or async depending on your use case).

Comment: Thank you! Lemme go through these links then I will add my questions. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I went through both the links, but couldn't find anything that gives me an introduction to process and its implementation for MQ V7.1. May you please direct me to a book or other similar resources?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to use?  JMS or MQI?

Comment: JMS will be the best, I believe.

Comment: Do you control the message format that is being placed on the queue?  Edited the answer since you are saying you want to use JMS now.

Comment: @gwhitake, could you please suggest which one is better JMS or MQI ? any specific advantages of one over another ?

Answer (score 2):

Message Service Client for .NET a.k.a XMS .NET is now part of WebSphere MQ v701. You can find latest documentation on XMS .NET [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp). XMS .NET gets installed along with MQ Client from v701 on-wards.